# Can someone explain how is the sorting being done in this line. I see that the sorting is being done using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

This is from one of the **leetcode** problems. I didn't understand why and how the split function is being used

```
 class Solution(object):
    def reorderLogFiles(self, logs):
        """
        :type logs: List[str]
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        
        letters= []
        digits = []
        
        for log in logs:
            split = log.split(" ")
            
            if split[1].isdigit():
                digits.append(log)
            else:
                letters.append(log)

        # Didn't get this line of code
        letters.sort(key=lambda x: (x.split(' ')[1:],x.split(' ')[0])) 
        
        return letters+digits
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a lambda expression for this. Define a regular function that calls `x.split` once, then returns the "rotated" list. You could probably use an assignment expression in a lambda expression.

Comment: `def foo(x): y = x.split(' '); return (y[1:], y[0])`, then `letter.sort(key=foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` is just a way to create a function in-place.  If you want to play with this particular function to get a feel for what it does, just assign it a name and feed it some strings.

```
>>> sort_key = lambda x: (x.split(' ')[1:],x.split(' ')[0])
>>> sort_key("foo bar")
(['bar'], 'foo')
>>> sort_key("the quick brown fox")
(['quick', 'brown', 'fox'], 'the')
```

When a function is used as the `key` argument to `sort`, each element of the list to be sorted is passed through that function before it's compared with the other items in the list.  In effect this key function makes it so the strings are sorted according to their second (space-separated) word.